# The .htaccess file exists but does not contain the correct content. It is possible it's been maliciously altered

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in the files directory and the .htaccess file permission is 444.

On running security review , I get the following response

```
"The .htaccess file exists but does not contain the correct content. It is possible 
it's been maliciously altered."
```

Is this a security breach?

I am trying to fix out the security check but facing the above issue.
I have even tried removing the .htaccess file and updated
with that of .htaccess file(`sites/default/files/.htaccess`) from fresh drupal install.

Still It shows the same error.
I would like to figure out the following issue.

I would also like to know the permissions which are assigned to .htaccess file and what should be the content inside it.?

Comment: This is the original .htaccess file https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess, permissions should be 644

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. where should I add the .htaccess file . is it inside the sites/default/files

Comment: that `.htaccess` most be on your drupal root directory.

this `.htaccess` should be on your `files` directory  https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003

Comment: Thanks @shirish but I am still facing the same issue and message when Run security review check

Comment: What security review are you running? Drupalgeddon? (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) Can you add a screenshot of the output of your security review.

Comment: I am running Security review module https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review